# How to use bones to modify the length, width and height of the packaging box

Tags: modeling

[Here is my model link](https://gentle-field-05667750f.3.azurestaticapps.net/assets/packingbox_custom_size.blend)

I need to import this model in three.js and then modify its bones to dynamically set the length, width and height of the packaging box.
[image]

This is how to modify the bones to change the height of the packed box, I tried adding other face bones to modify the length and width, but the box became distorted

Comment: Would scaling be an option?

Comment: Scaling will affect the proportion of the lid of the express box, causing it to fail to close

Comment: Oh, I see. With a non-uniform scale the rotated bones act really wonky.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try but I don't know if it works when exported to Three.js.

[image: animation of a scaled box that opens and closes]
<sup>There should a rabbit jump out at the end...</sup>

The mesh is a box that is open at the top. It's deformed by the *Scale* bone. The 4 side parts and the bottom are assigned to the *Scale* vertex group with a weight of 1.0.

There are also 4 loose mesh parts as "lids" to close the box. Each of these parts is assigned to a bone via a vertex group. You can join all parts into a single object if you like.

The 4 lids bones (*Top-X*) are children of the *Scale* bone which is a child of the *Root* bone. The *Root* bone is just a control bone to move the box. It has the `[_]` *Deform* checkbox not set.

If you align all deformation bones to the global axis and set *Inherit Scale* to `Algined` for the *Top-X* bones then the rotation works with a non-uniform scale, e.g. scale = (1.0, 0.5, 2.0). Otherwise, the lid panel grows and shrinks while it is rotated.

[image: box with bones]